# Excel 2010 is lower rounding a number entered as a custom format for a credit card number

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have used the custom format for a cell as follows

```
####-####-####-####
```

When I enter the credit card number it will round down only the last number to a zero "0", no matter what number is entered.

Answer (score 1):

Excel only recognizes 15 digits per cell after that it will turn any additional digits to a zero.

Comment: Since you aren't doing math on a credit card number, enter it as text.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this behavior, format the cell as text (as mentioned in the comments), then type the numbers. The cell can then display up to 1,024 characters.

This behavior only occurs with numbers that are intended for calculation, that is, in cells that are formatted as numbers. In cells that are formatted as text, you can type up to 32,767 characters, of which Excel displays up to 1,024 characters on the worksheet.

Because custom number formats are designed to work primarily with numbers, you cannot create a custom number format that stores more than 15 digits. For example, you cannot use the following format to store a 16-character credit card ID as a number:

-####-####-

If you type the number 1111222233334444 in a cell that uses the ####-####-####-#### format, Excel displays 1111-2222-3333-4440 in the cell. The actual number that you are attempting to store is 1,111,222,233,334,444, which is over one quadrillion. But because this number is so large, Excel drops the last (least significant) digit, and puts a zero in its place.

If you type the number in the cell that is formatted as text, all the characters remain as you type them, because Excel does not attempt to store the credit card id as a number, but leaves it as text.

Source:
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/269370/en-us

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, Excel only recognizes 15 digits per cell. Credit card numbers are never used as numbers (adding, multiplying, etc.), so just enter them as text. You can hit the apostrophe (`'`) before entering the numbers to ensure that they are treated as text.

If you don't want to type the dashes, you can use a formula in a different column to add the dashes into your string.

```
=MID(A1,1,4)&"-"&MID(A1,5,4)&"-"&MID(A1,9,4)&"-"&MID(A1,13,4)
```

This will convert this string:

```
1234567890123456
```

To this:

```
1234-5678-9012-3456
```

Alternatively you could enter each set of four digits into a new cell and use the following formula to construct your credit card number:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0000")&"-"&TEXT(B1,"0000")&"-"&TEXT(C1,"0000")&"-"&TEXT(D1,"0000")
```